# Two reCaptcha on one page, how to verify in php?

Tags: php, recaptcha

i am trying to use 2x reCapcha on one page that has 2 forms. I managet to show them separately, bude i cant verify the data now. To verify i use two separate functions like this

```
$recaptcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
if(!empty($recaptcha)) {
    $google_url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
    $secret = 'secret';
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $url = $google_url."secret=".$secret."&response=".$recaptcha."&remoteip=".$ip;
    $res = getCurlData($url);
    $res = json_decode($res, true);
    ...
    if($res['success']) { do stuff }
```

to load my 2 capchas i use

```
<script src="//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=myCallBack&render=explicit" async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var recaptcha1;
  var recaptcha2;
  var myCallBack = function() {
    //Render the recaptcha1 on the element with ID "recaptcha1"
    recaptcha1 = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha1', {
      'sitekey' : 'key', //Replace this with your Site key
      'theme' : 'light'
    });

    //Render the recaptcha2 on the element with ID "recaptcha2"
    recaptcha2 = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha2', {
      'sitekey' : 'key', //Replace this with your Site key
      'theme' : 'light'
    });
  };
</script>
```

can somebody help me how can i do it? Is this even posible?

Comment: http://mycodde.blogspot.ca/2014/12/multiple-recaptcha-demo-same-page.html this might help

Comment: Thx, i am using this article in my code. But i have problems to verify recaptcha with php code. I really think it is not posible with 2 recaptchas.

Comment: will be able to test something this evening, in the meanwhile if you get a resolution, please share

Answer (score 0):

You a doing kind of tricky thing.

First of all you need to be clear how does reCaptcha [work](https://webscraping.pro/no-captcha-recaptcha-challenge/). 
Now I direct you to the [post](https://webscraping.pro/insert-configure-recaptcha-no-captcha-code-in-php/) on how to insert it and proceed validation client side.

**1. Register at Google** - you'll have the same site key and secret key for both reCaptchas.

**2. Insert a form with the CAPTCHAs on your site** - you will need to have a  forms with recaptchas, having **2 different callbacks** for verifying each one of them.

### Form:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" >;
<form method="post">
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="[site_key]" data-callback="onReturnCallback1" data-theme="light"></div>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="[site_key]" data-callback="onReturnCallback2" data-theme="dark"></div>
<input value="submit" type="submit" />
</form>
```

**3. JavaScript code to decode the response** - you'll need to define 2 callbacks to verify each reCaptcha separatly. As you've done it you store the verification result in JS variable.

```
<script> src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var success1=null, success2=null;
var onReturnCallback1 = function(response) { 
    //alert('g-recaptcha-response: ' + grecaptcha.getResponse()); 
    var url='proxy.php?url=' + 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';  
    $.ajax({ 'url' : url, 
               dataType: 'json',
               data: { response: response},
               success: function( data  ) {                     
               var res = data.success.toString();                   
               if (res ==  'true') { 
                        success1=true;
                        if (success1&&success2) { 
                             // do form submission
                        } 
                    } 
               } // end of success: 
         }); // end of $.ajax 
}; // end of onReturnCallback 
</script>
```

Inside of each callback you save success results in `success1` & `success2` and check if both are successful to force form submition:

```
if (success1&&success2) { 
    // do form submission
}
```

**4. Proxy on your server that returns true or false** - seems only one proxy file is needed for each reCaptchas to verify site.

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    die('You are not allowed to access this file.');     
}
header('Content-type: application/json');
$url=$_GET['url'];
$response=$_GET['response'];
$secret = "[secter_key]"; 
$params = array('secret'=&gt; $secret, 'response'=&gt; $response);
$json=file_get_contents( $url  . '?secret=' . $secret . '&amp;response=' . $response);
echo $json;
```